# C++ integer literal type

Tags: c++, literals

In "C++ Primer (Fifth edition)", it says:

> The type of an integer literal depends on its value and notation.
>   By default, decimal literals are signed whereas octal and hexadecimal literals can be either signed or unsigned types.
>   A decimal literal has the smallest type of int, long, or long long in which the literal's value fits.
>   Octal and hexadecimal literals have the smallest type of int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, or unsigned long long
>   in which the literal's value fits.

Running the following code in Visual C++ 2015:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void verify_type(int a) { cout << "int" << endl; }
void verify_type(long a) { cout << "long" << endl; }
void verify_type(long long a) { cout << "long long" << endl; }
void verify_type(unsigned int a) { cout << "unsigned int" << endl; }
void verify_type(unsigned long a) { cout << "unsigned long" << endl;  }
void verify_type(unsigned long long a) { cout << "unsigned long long" << endl; }

int main()
{
    cout << "The value of INT_MAX is " << INT_MAX << endl;
    cout << "The value of INT_MIN is " << INT_MIN << endl;
    verify_type(2147483648);
    verify_type(0x80000000U);
    verify_type(0x80000000);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
The value of INT_MAX is 2147483647
The value of INT_MIN is -2147483648
unsigned long
unsigned int
unsigned int
```

I would expect that `verify_type(2147483648)` would be `long long`. Why do I get `unsigned long`?

Comment: With clang and gcc, `verify_type(2147483648)` is outputting `long` for me. I'm guessing this might be a bug in MSVC. It might be worth trying in a more recent version of MSVC to see if it's been fixed.

Comment: VC2017 has the same (wrong) output as OP.

Comment: MSVC intentionally doesn't comply with the standard

Comment: Is not it ‘long long’?